# Python: How to convert variables and their respective strings into a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following 4 strings

```
line1 = 'be nice'
line2 = '"best!"'
line3 = 'better?'
line4 = 'oh no\nbear spotted'
```

Is there a way for me to convert them into a table using pandas without hard coding?
For example:

| Line | String |
| --- | --- |
| line1 | be nice |
| line2 | "best!" |
| line3 | better? |
| line4 | oh no\nbear spotted |

Thank you!

Comment: Check this example out:
`
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> df2
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
`

Comment: [link]https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/dsintro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"Line": line, "String": eval(line)} for line in dir() 
    if line.startswith("line")
])
```